# Как создать ветку в git от произвольного места?

Tags: git, git-branch

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в git создать ветку от коммита, который не является текущим?

Т.е, допустим, мне в ветке требуется работать со старой версией файлов, как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
git branch <branch-name> <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 14):

Делаете checkout на нужный коммит

```
git checkout <commit_id>
```

и, если нужно, создаете новый бранч как обычно

```
git branch <newbranch>
```

Comment: Поддерживаю этот способ, т.к. он позволяет явным образом проверить, что находится в рабочей области целевого коммита. Тот ли это коммит, который я имел в виду.

Answer (score 3):

Для полноты картины — есть ещё такой способ:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name> <commit-id>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Т.е, допустим, мне в ветке требуется работать со старой версией файлов, как я могу это сделать?*

Если нужно работать со старым файлом, то я предпочитаю "вытянуть" конкретный файл из коммита

```
git checkout dbfa07b813a78072663 -- lib/tasks/fill_brand_id.rake
```

где 
*dbfa07b813a78072663* - номер коммита

*lib/tasks/fill_brand_id.rake* - путь к файлу